# Reduction techniques (word, planar model)

Tags: algebraic-topology

I don´t understand how this word (build from a standard model) can be transformed in this way:

$$abca^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1} = aba^{-1}b^{-1}cc^{-1}$$

For completeness I put the next (it is trivial): $$aba^{-1}b^{-1}cc^{-1} = T \# cc^{-1} = T \# S^2 = T$$

Thank you all.

Excuse me, YAlexandrov, but following your instruction (I suppose in the same sense) I obtain:

[image]

And still I don´t see how you get $T \# S^2$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I apologize. Indeed I think first step is wrong. In this case, how is the solution?

Comment: In the RHS rename $c$ to be $a^{-1}$, rename $a$ to be $b$ and rename $b$ to be $c$. Then start reading the cycle from what was before the last $c^{-1}$, which is now $a$.

Comment: Thanks YAlexandrov! But still I don´t see the procediment. Can you write it? Also, I´m not sure that to rename letters be a valid reduction technique. Is it? I only suppose 1. change "orientation" of edges (or pair of edges); example $aba^{-1}c = a^{-1}bac^{-1}$, 2. write the word in the inverse order, example: $aba^{-1}c = c^{-1}ab^{-1}a^{-1}$ and 3. Move set of letters from the final to the beginning, example $aba^{-1}c = a^{-1}cab$. Are this transformations valid? Sincerely, thank you very much!

Comment: Draw the loop with arrows to mark the orientation of the paths and do what I said.

Comment: Hi YAlexandrof. Up there is the picture. Is it right?